# Error running rviz: Xlib: extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0.0"

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ubuntu-quantal, ros-groovy, nvidia

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I cannot get rviz to start.
I did

```
rosdep install rviz
rosmake rviz
```

They both run fine; when I run

```
rosrun rviz rviz
```

I get the following error (it tries 100x and gives me the same error that many times):

```
rviz::RenderSystem: error creating render window: std::exception
Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
[ WARN] [1359884146.909768203]: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): Unable to create a suitable GLXContext in GLXContext::GLXContext at /build/buildd/ogre-1.7.4/RenderSystems/GL/src/GLX/OgreGLXContext.cpp (line 61)
rviz::RenderSystem: error creating render window: std::exception
[ERROR] [1359884146.909883164]: Unable to create the rendering window after 100 tries.
rviz: /tmp/buildd/ros-groovy-rviz-1.9.20-0quantal-20130126-0146/src/rviz/ogre_helpers/render_system.cpp:272: Ogre::RenderWindow* rviz::RenderSystem::makeRenderWindow(intptr_t, unsigned int, unsigned int): Assertion `false' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

My system: Ubuntu 12.10 32b, GeForce GT 630M, ROS Groovy.

I am going to update this post with other info as described in http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/Troubleshooting#How_to_make_a_usable_bug_report, unless someone recognizes this problem right away.

EDIT: Following the instructions in this answer http://answers.ros.org/question/10588/rviz-does-not-start-prints-glxunsupportedprivaterequest/?answer=15671#post-id-15671 got rid of the previous errors, now the rviz window opens up for a second and then crashes. I am getting:

```
[ INFO] [1359888641.886868366]: rviz version 1.9.20
[ INFO] [1359888641.887071444]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.4 (Cthugha)
[ WARN] [1359888644.497027605]: OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Cannot compile GLSL high-level shader : rviz/pass_pos_color.vert Cannot compile GLSL high-level shader : rviz/pass_pos_color.vert 0:1(15): preprocessor error: syntax error, unexpected IDENTIFIER, expecting NEWLINE
 in GLSLProgram::compile at /build/buildd/ogre-1.7.4/RenderSystems/GL/src/GLSL/src/OgreGLSLExtSupport.cpp (line 65)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

EDIT 2: Same as before, tried it a couple more times, now rviz window appears. No idea why.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54090/error-running-rviz:-xlib:--extension-%22nv-glx%22-missing-on-display-%22:0.0%22/) by [Cristina](https://answers.ros.org/users/3909/cristina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2013-02-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2013-02-14**:
In my laptop I've got an nvidia optimus grahics card and I'm only able to run rviz using bumblebee by running "optirun rosrun rviz rviz".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had this issue.

I resolved it by installing nvidia drivers.

In ubuntu, I clicked on the little gear in the top-right corner, then I clicked "System Settings".

In that menu, I selected "Additional Drivers"

I was able to select to install NVIDIA drivers onto my laptop.

After the lengthy download and install, I could start rviz.

---

Originally posted by [MichaelGregg](https://answers.ros.org/users/17861/michaelgregg/) with karma: 41 on 2014-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tomcat](https://answers.ros.org/users/72927/tomcat/) on 2021-04-05**:
thank you it helps !